# Access from my machine to RDS is lost when a public subnet with an internet gateway and private subnets with NAT are added

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I have a Lambda function inside a VPC that needs a connection to the internet and a connection to a RDS database.

I have set up 6 private subnets (defaults from RDS) and 1 public subnet.

I have 2 routing tables

**A public routing table:**

- This table contains the one public subnet and routes it to a Internet Gateway (0.0.0.0/0)

**A private routing table**

- This table contains the 6 private subnets and routes them to a NAT gateway (0.0.0.0/0)

This is all working fine; the lambda inside the VPC has access to the RDS and the internet.

Now I want to connect to the RDS database on my machine to manage the database.

However, I can't seem to connect to my RDS database on my machine. It only works when I change the route on the private routing table **from** A NAT gateway **to** an Internet gateway. (but this causes the Lambda to **loose** connection to the internet).

Therefore my question is, how do I connect my machine to the RDS database without my lambda function losing access to the internet.

**Note:** There are already Inbound security groups setup for traffic from my IP and the IP of the NAT gateway

to summarize:

I set up a Lambda function in a VPC with access to the internet and an RDS database via private subnets and a NAT gateway. I expected to connect to the RDS database on my machine, but only managed it by changing the routing table to an internet gateway, which caused the Lambda to lose internet access. I need to connect my machine to the RDS without affecting the Lambda's internet access.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Just to get some context have you gone through [Tutorial: Connect an Amazon EC2 instance to an Amazon RDS database](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/tutorial-connect-ec2-instance-to-rds-database.html)? There's some permissions and security group setup parts for doing that kind of connectivity.

Comment: The database is in a **private subnet**, so you cannot directly connect to it. This is _GOOD_ because it provides added security. To access the database, you would need to use a Jump Box / Bastion Server in the public subnet and use Port Forwarding via SSH to access the database. Alternatively, you could use [Port Forwarding Using AWS System Manager Session Manager | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-port-forwarding-using-aws-system-manager-sessions-manager/) via an Amazon EC2 instance in a public or private subnet.

Answer (score 0):

The database would have to be in a public subnet for you to access it from your local computer. In other words, the database has to be in a public subnet to be publicly accessible.

> It only works when I change the route on the private routing table from A NAT gateway to an Internet gateway. (but this causes the Lambda to loose connection to the internet).

This action converts the private subnets into public subnets, which as you have noticed breaks your Lambda function's Internet access.

---

You either need to move your database into public subnets, or you need to use some other means of connecting to the database, such as a jump box in the public subnet.